# Does anyone know how to handle browser authentication

Tags: zalenium

I am trying to run the tests using Zalenium but the browser is asking for the credentials, so I am providing the username and password manually.

Does anyone know how to handle browser authentication?

My project uses Specflow, C# and Selenium

Answer (score 0):

There are several options

1. You can login with http://username:password@website.com/page
2. Automate login process at @BeforeMethod or @BeforeClass
3. Set cookies. Although I don't advise this method since it doesn't speed up automation much and there is quite a bit of work to do to implement it.

Comment: I have tried option 1 but it doesn't seem to work and I don't think option 2 will work either.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your web application behind a proxy that automatically injects the basic auth credentials. I did this once for a client a few years back.

I'm pretty sure I used: https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy with https://github.com/ganskef/LittleProxy-mitm

But I had to write some code intercept requests and inject basic auth headers.  Although from memory it was pretty straight forward.

If you don't need https then you could probably use [cntlm](https://hub.docker.com/r/robertdebock/docker-cntlm) and then set the basic auth header by hand using this:

```
        -r  "HeaderName: value"
        Add a header substitution. All such headers will be added/replaced
        in the client's requests.
```

Comment: I think I will try using cntlm. Thanks